# ng-show doesn't work when used with custom directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to hide the text when clicked on Close link which is in the template by executing it within the context of the parent scope. But it doesn't work. Can someone tell me where I went wrong.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="parking">
<head>
    <title>Parking</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app=angular.module('parking', []);
        app.controller('parkingCtrl', function($scope){
            $scope.show=true;
            $scope.alertTopic="Something went Wrong!";
            $scope.alertDescription="Try Again!";
            $scope.closeAlert=function(){
                $scope.show=false;
            };
        });
        app.directive('alert', function(){
            return {
                templateUrl:"alert.html",
                restrict: "E",
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    topic: "=topic",
                    description: "=description",
                    close: "&close"
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="parkingCtrl">
    <alert
        ng-show="show"
        topic="alertTopic"
        description="alertDescription"
        close="closeAlert"
    ></alert>
</body>
</html>

<!--alert.html-->
<div class="alert">
    <span class="alert-topic">
     <span ng-bind="topic"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="alert-description">
    <span ng-bind="description"></span>
    </span>
    <a href="" ng-click="close()">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: From that inner html you need to do `$parent.show` as you have created directive with isolated scope.. **OR** you need to pass that variable in isolated scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change close="closeAlert" to close="closeAlert()" like:

```
<alert
    ng-show="show"
    topic="alertTopic"
    description="alertDescription"
    close="closeAlert()"
></alert>
```

Because angular It wraps your function with another function if you use & char [example](http://jsbin.com/kaxiluriji/1/edit?html,js,output)